# Allow deletion recommendation for questions in VLQ (Q)

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, low-quality-posts

Often I see stuff like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43924423/how-to-uninstall-telerik-justdecompile

and this answer got to the queue:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52201132/6881240

At first glance, it looked like it was an OK answer - a list of stuff to do to fix the OP's problem. But, I noticed while the answer seemed OK (as an answer, debatable but I would have let it go) there was no way it belonged on the site, and indeed the question is off topic.

The whole post looks weird (see OPs user name, the other, much worse answer). **Can we get a way to recommend question deletion in the VLQ?** Bad questions tend to attract bad answers, and this would be a good place to catch them.

**Note**

I advised the user to delete the answer and they kindly agreed, but stupidly I did not take a screenshot. If a high rep can post it here I would appreciate it.

Answer (score -2):

Don't worry about it too much; you're only reviewing the answer (though looking at the question is certainly a good idea), so "Looks OK" is an acceptable review.

*However*, if you noticed that *the question* is off-topic, then I would recommend these actions:

- Lightly chastise the user who posted the answer, since they're not supposed to answer off-topic questions.
- Open the question with the link available from review and flag/vote to close.
- Post it to [SOCVR chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) if you think it's necessary:

  > cv-pls is for questions that:
  >
  > - are really bad (low quality magnets)
  > - are a bad example used to justify other crap
  > - **have recent activity on the question (Edits, VLQ/NAA answer)**
  > - don't have enough users in that tag to close the question in time
  >
  > (From [their FAQ](https://socvr.org/faq#general-expectations-for-members), emphasis is mine)

These might not even be necessary; the new answer will bump it to the top, so in a large enough tag the high reputation users will likely get to it.

Given all of the options listed above, I'm not entirely sure why your suggestion is necessary.

Comment: To be honest, what you suggest is a lot of work (and is in fact, what I did). When going over the queue I do not want to manually go into each question to deal with it. A bulletin to open the close question menu would be helpful to quickly dispense of these instead of creating more work.